# Proxy Authentication requred

Tags: vb.net

On most PCs these codelines (WebClient, DownloadFile) are working:

```
Dim wc As New WebClient
Dim arr As Byte() = wc.DownloadData("https://my.server/file.txt")
[...]
My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile("https://my.server/file.txt", "c:\temp\file.txt")
[...]
```

Other PCs have been configured to use a Proxy and the administrator told me "users are allowed to connect to the internet, their machines not".

In both cases the result is

> System.Net.WebException: Der Remoteserver hat einen Fehler
> zurückgegeben: (407) Proxyauthentifizierung erforderlich.
> In English possibly "The Remoteserver throw an error: (407) Proxyauthtication required"

How can I "tell" the WebClient and my.computer.network.downloadfile that they should use the system's settings for using their proxy and that it should use their user credentials?

Comment: [Automatic Proxy Detection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/automatic-proxy-detection). If the proxy is configured to use the default NetworkCredentials, you can use the [CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.credentialcache.defaultnetworkcredentials) as the `WebClient.Proxy.Credentials`. Otherwise, pass a `new WebProxy()` object, setting the Credentials as described and the Address as, e.g., `new Uri(new UriBuilder("IPAddress:Port").Uri.ToString(), UriKind.Absolute)`